# Why am I not able to add directory in linux $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, .bash-profile

I am trying to add `~/.bin` into my path and for that I edited the `.bash_profile` and added the below line

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.bin/
```

and than I logged out/in.

Now when I do `echo $PATH` I get

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

and you can see there is no `~/.bin` directory added .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to `source .bash_profile`, and `echo $PATH` to see if your path got updated. If yes, it means your `.bash_profile` is not read upon log-in.

Comment: `source .bash_profile` worked. How can I make sure that `.bash_profile` is read upon log-in.

Comment: Well, it's kind of hard to answer, it depends how you login. You can read the section `INVOCATION` of `man bash` to see which file is read when...

Comment: @Noob: [This might](http://askubuntu.com/a/121075/32063) give you some insight.

Comment: I think your problem is that you want to put the line in `~/.bashrc` instead.

Comment: But I thought that to add a folder to path `.bash_profile` is the file to be edited and not `.bashrc`.

Comment: Look at the link @RanRag posted, it explain the section of the man bash that I was talking about.

Comment: @m4573r: Yes I read it and it certainly cleared my doubt. Thanks